# GSON installation

Tags: java, json, eclipse

So I'm working on a server application, and i'd like to use json to serialize data into packets to send between the server and the client. However, I"m having a lot of trouble with actually adding the library to eclipse. Usually, I use Build Path to add external .jar files, but the repository i'm using for gson -> https://github.com/google/gson only has .java files. Am I missing something very obvious, or do i just make a folder and drag the .java files in?

Note: I'm a relatively beginner to intermediate java programmer, so some things might need a bit of explaining.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JAR files from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/). Keep in mind, if you have the .java files you can actually compile the files yourself and turn them into .jars.

I would HIGHLY recommend you invest some time into understanding how Maven works. When you add more and more dependencies it will become a nightmare manually downloading them and managing them yourself.